# Query for cross matching multiple joined tables

Tags: postgresql

I have four tables, such that:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE country (
  countryid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE city (
  cityid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  countryid int REFERENCES country
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE user_country (
  userid int,
  countryid int REFERENCES country
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE user_city (
  userid int,
  cityid int REFERENCES city
);
```

I'm trying to write a query which will match users up based on their user_country and user_city entries, so that any one hit will produce a match if,

1. a user has any of the same `user_country` or `user_city` entries as another user.
2. given the relationship between city and country; if one user has an entry in the `user_country` table and another user has an entry in the `user_city` table with a city that is in the first `users_country`, this will also produce a match.

For example, given the following example data and the user `id` `1`, the query will return the user ids `2`, `3`, `4`: `2` is matched in the `user_country` table (both users have an entry containing the `country_id` `1`) and user `id`s `3` and `4` are matched because their entries in the `user_city` table relate to London which has a `country_id` which matches user id `1`'s `user_country` entry. (In laymans terms, user `1` wants to go anywhere in England, so does user `2`, producing a match; users `3` and `4` are more specific but because both London and Leeds are in England they both produce matches)

Given the same data and the user `id` `3`, the query will return the user id `1` and `2`, as the `country_id` in the `city` table relates to the country that both users `1` and `2` have selected, but not user `4`. (in laymans terms, user `3` wants to go to London; users `1` and `2` want to go anywhere in England, so they match.  However user `4` only wants to go to Leeds, not London, so doesn't match)

```
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('England'),('Canada');
INSERT INTO city (name,countryid) VALUES ('London',1),('Leeds',1),('Vancouver',2);

INSERT INTO user_country (userid, countryid) VALUES (1,1),(2,1);
INSERT INTO user_city (userid, cityid) VALUES (3,1),(4,2);
```

Can anyone help me with a single performant SQL query, that given a user `id`, returns a list of user ids which match the above scenarios?

Note: I'm using a recent version of postgres

*EDIT*
To clarify a few points: a user can have an entry in the `user_city` table without a corresponding entry in the `user_country` table for the country matching the city.  This is because a user may have an interest in visiting a city, but not want to see the rest of the country.  Being able to select a country is a shorthand way of selecting every single city in that country.
In layman's terms: just because a user wants to visit London, they don't necessarily want to visit all of the UK. So a user can have a user_city entry for London, but not have a user_country entry for the UK; also worth noting that if a user has a user_country entry for the UK, they won't have any user_city entries for any cities in that country (user wants to visit all of the UK, so doesn't make sense to list London too).

Separately a city will always be in a country, so will always have a country_id

*EDIT 2*
A bit more example data to replace the data above (not in addition to!)

```
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Germany'),('Spain'),('Italy');
INSERT INTO city (name,countryid) VALUES ('Berlin',1),('Madrid',2),('Rome',3),('Venice',3);

INSERT INTO user_country (userid, countryid) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(5,3)
INSERT INTO user_city (userid, cityid) VALUES (3,2),(4,2),(6,3),(7,4)
```

Testing a match only on matching user_country table entries:

- Entering user id 1 returns user id 2
- Entering user id 2 returns user id 1

Testing a match only on matching user_city table entries:

- Entering user id 3 returns user id 4
- Entering user id 4 returns user id 3

Testing that a user_country matches all entries with related cities:

- Entering user id 5 returns user ids 6 & 7

Testing that a user_city entry picks up a user_country entry:

- Entering user id 6 returns user id 5
- Entering user id 7 returns user id 5

Comment: Does every city have a country?

Comment: @evancarroll yes, every city has a country

Comment: user_id 3 shouldn't ppear on the user_country table?

Comment: I'm confused what does it mean that *every city has a country*, and not at the same time that every `user_city` does not have a `user_country`.. That's kind of why I asked. Anyway, it's only the diff between an inner join, and a left join in my query.

Comment: @EvanCarroll in laymans terms: I meant that because a user wants to visit London, they don't necessarily want to visit all of the UK. So a user can have a `user_city` entry for London, but not have a `user_country` entry for the UK; also worth noting that if a user has a `user_country` entry for the UK, they won't have any `user_city` entries for any cities in that country (user wants to visit all of the UK, so doesn't make sense to list London too).
Separately a `city` will always be in a `country`, so will always have a `country_id`

Comment: Why don't you load it up with data, or more data and then tell us *exactly* the table you want as the result set. 0-English needed.

Answer (score 1):

## Sample Data

This is actually very easy, first let's create your schema. Next time around, it's better and easier for everyone if you provide data like this.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE country (
  countryid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE city (
  cityid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  countryid int REFERENCES country
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE user_country (
  userid int,
  countryid int REFERENCES country
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE user_city (
  userid int,
  cityid int REFERENCES city
);
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('England'),('Canada');
INSERT INTO city (name,countryid) VALUES ('London',1),('Leeds',1),('Vancouver',1);
INSERT INTO user_country (userid, countryid) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(4,2);
INSERT INTO user_city (userid, cityid) VALUES (3,1),(4,2),(2,3);
```

## Solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_city_country.userid AS user1,
  user_country.userid AS user2
FROM user_country
JOIN country USING (countryid)
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM user_city
  JOIN city USING (cityid)
  JOIN country USING (countryid)
) AS user_city_country
  USING (countryid);
```

This breaks down easy... Path one is to resolve the user to the country..

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_country.userid
FROM user_country
JOIN country USING (countryid)
```

Path 2 is to resolve the `user_city` to the country.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_city
JOIN city USING (cityid)
JOIN country USING (countryid)
```

Then we just `JOIN` them. Note, we're not actually using the `country` at all. You have it in your schema. So I preserved it here.

This returns...

```
 user1 | user2 
-------+-------
     4 |     2
     3 |     1
     2 |     1
     3 |     2
     4 |     1
     2 |     2
```

Now, if you want to know all matches, just add `WHERE user_country.userid = '1' OR user_city_country.userid = '1';`

```
 user1 | user2 
-------+-------
     4 |     1
     3 |     1
     2 |     1
```

Comment: Yes!  This seems to work in my test cases.  I'm going to throw some more data at it and see if it breaks.  I appreciate your constructive criticism in regards to the schema and will take that on board for next time (SQL isn't my forte, so always good to learn something)

Comment: Doesn't quite work as per my requirements.  For example, if two users have matching entries in the `user_country` table, but nothing in the `user_city` table then no match is found.  To replicate, remove all entries in the 'user_city' table, user id's 1 and 2 should match as they both have a matching entry in the user_country table

Comment: I've given some more example data - I hope that clears up where my description is falling short.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understant your request, but take a shot at the following query and comment if does what you mean:

```
-- For ease, we have the user_id of the first 'visitor'
WITH my_user (user_id) AS
(
    VALUES (1)
)
-- List the countries that (my_user.user_id) wants to visit
, my_countries (country_id) AS
(
SELECT 
    country_id 
FROM 
    user_country 
    JOIN my_user USING (user_id)
UNION
SELECT  -- Contryies of interest via city...
    country_id
FROM 
    user_city
    JOIN my_user USING(user_id)
    JOIN city ON city.id = user_city.city_id 
)
-- Users that want to go the same 'country'
SELECT DISTINCT
    uc.user_id
FROM
    my_countries
    JOIN user_country uc USING(country_id)

UNION
-- Users that want to go to some 'city' that is in my_countries
SELECT DISTINCT
    ui.user_id
FROM
    my_countries
    JOIN city USING (country_id)
    JOIN user_city ui ON city.id = ui.city_id

EXCEPT
-- Myself
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    my_user ;
```

Comment: It's a good attempt, and satisfies use case 1 (user id 1 returns 2, 3 & 4) but not usecase 2 (user id 3 returns nothing).  Thank you though, I like the way you structured your code!

Comment: @Martyn: Updated to take that into account too

Comment: Still not quite right - with the initial example data it's returning all user ids for each user id entered.  I've given some more example data - hope that helps!